# Вопрос по знакам препинания.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.
Безотносительно политики.Не хочу никого оскорбить.Просто любопытство.

Если предложение выглядит так:

Кто не скачет у того Крым и газ.

Как расставляются знаки в таком предложении?

Comment: а если не секрет, это фраза случайным образом сгенерирована, или за ней какой-то смысл стоит?
Она чем нибудь от "кто не плачет, у того хлеб и квас" отличается?

И вот еще есть похожее.

Хорошо тому живется,   
У кого стеклянный глаз.  
Он не колется, не бьется - 
и сверкает как алмаз.

Comment: Просто нацистски настроенная молодежь в Киеве устроила такой цирк: все прыгали и скандировали: "Хто не скаче, той москаль". Зрелище было жуткое - как одержимые сектанты.

Comment: Вот не знаете где, так и не говорите. Может, это в Подмосковье снимали.

Comment: >Просто нацистски настроенная молодежь в Киеве   
  
Не вижу ничего нацистского. Но это ладно, не тут обсуждать.
По сути - понял, это типа ответка такая. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что здесь сложного? Кто не скачет, у того Крым и газ (запятая между частями сложноподчиненного предложения)

Comment: Спасибо,засомневался просто;)

Comment: Можете  кликнуть "принять ответ"